# Docker Compose make an random network IP range

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, ip, subnet

My project is bilding from several docker-compose*.yml files stored in one directory.

I describe network in one of them (called common) like this:

```
networks:
    main-net:
        name: main-net_network
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            config:
            - subnet: 172.23.3.0/24
              gateway: 172.23.3.1
    jmx-net:
        name: jmx_network
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            config:
            - subnet: 172.23.4.0/24
              gateway: 172.23.4.1
    nginx-proxy-net:
            name: nginx-proxy-network
```

and in another docker-compose files like this:

```
networks:
     main-net:
         name: main-net_network
     jmx-net:
         name: jmx_network
     nginx-proxy-net:
         name: nginx-proxy-network
```

If service need to be bind to IP I describe it like this:

```
networks:
            main-net:
                ipv4_address: 172.23.3.201
```

if service can be runned on any IP of this network/networks it looks like:

```
networks:
            - main-net
```

So all this projects was written couple years ago and all was fine. Right now, some projects stuck on CI/CD on error:

`Error response from daemon: user specified IP address is supported only when connecting to networks with user configured subnets`

As I can see at this time - network created with another IP subnet (can be even 192.168.X.X, depends on Docker settings). And when service wants to be attached to network main-net with specific IP - issue is happen.

Right now I just decribe IP subnets in each docker-compose file. But I'm discouraged a bit ... because in old times all was fine. Maybe docker updates make some changes?

I'm setting version "2" in the top of docker-compose file and using docker version 20.10.21 on my server.

I will be pleased for any help from you.
Regards.

Comment: Do you have the corresponding `services:` definitions?  I'd suggest removing all of the manual IP address configuration and let Docker assign the addresses itself: you can't normally access these addresses from outside Docker, and inside Docker you can use its native DNS system without knowing the specific IP addresses.  It's possible you don't even need multiple networks, and you can delete all of the `networks:` blocks everywhere to use the Compose-provided `default` network.

Comment: David, thanks for your reply. I think you have a point. Yes, you're correct, I've make definitions of service: . Unfortunately, I have many stacks inside docker and they have similar names. That's why I can't use name of service instead IP's (recently I was have an issue when microservice goes to another by name and get data from another stack). That's why I'm using direct IP's. And I'm understand that code can be not clearly written in microservice, but we have it in prod and I need to work with it :))

Comment: This is where I'm suggesting deleting _all_ of the `networks:` blocks.  Compose will create a different `default` network for each project and you shouldn't have these conflicts.  Manually specifying the external `name:` of each network can lead to conflicts like what you describe.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I got your point. Will try to do this.